# how to make icarousel show items in different order

Tags: ios, icarousel

I use the icarousel class for my project. (This an awesome tool BTW. Thanks to the author.)

I'm trying to reach the following view:

[image: (img1 - needed)]

What seems pretty easy. But it is important to keep 2 following items below the current item and just one previously observed by user item on the top. I've reached the similar view pretty easy:

[image: (img2 - reached effect)]

As you can see the order of items is reversed. The view shows one following item below the current item and two previously observed on the top of the view.

Please advise me how to reach effect requested in the first image.

P.S.: Sorry for the links. I do not have enough reputation to post images yet.

Comment: I tried to find where the iCarousel class setts the 2-nd item from the bottom as a current item or where it defines how many items should be preloaded before the current item. But I didn't succeed to find any of that.

Comment: In a normal carousel (e.g. rotary, wheel, etc.) it wants to be balanced. So it would normally show 2 above and 2 below your central image. Have you tried expanding the view offscreen so the top is truncated offscreen? Or you could try writing a custom transform:
You can also implement your own bespoke carousel styles using iCarouselTypeCustom and the carousel:itemTransformForOffset:baseTransform: delegate method.

Comment: For more on how the standard transforms work see the source code for - (CATransform3D)transformForItemViewWithOffset:(CGFloat)offset 
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/blob/master/iCarousel/iCarousel.m

Comment: @Funktional, you are right. It does want to be balanced and adds 2 items above and 2 items below the central item. But when I set the number of visible items to 4. It removes the item from the bottom but not from the top. Unfortunately the carousel:itemTransformForOffset:baseTransform method helps me to set the custom rotation animation but it still holds one visible item from the bottom. It looks like i miss something. Thank you for you trying to help.

Comment: Also when iCarouselOptionWrap is set to NO the iCarousel rotates from the bottom. I believe it would help to reverse the rotation direction.